# Subdomain on localhost

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I would like to create a registration form which creates subdomains (yet on localhost), but I have got some problem. I know how to create subdomains, writing for example these in vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.hleclerc-PC.ingenidev
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/something/"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias something.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And put this line in hosts:

```
127.0.0.0              something.localhost
```

It's working, but what I want is that when I register a new subdomain (for example: other), then when I try to open other.localhost, then it opens the specified folder (../www/other/).
I tried it in vhosts with "ServerName *.localhost", "ServerName localhost", "ServerAlias *.localhost", "ServerAlias localhost", and in hosts "127.0.0.1 *.localhost" with all of the permutation of these, but neither of these worked for me.
I have thinked about it, that on registration I put a new block in vhosts, with the optimal data, but I don't think it's very safe/feasible/or the best way to do.

Hope someone can help me!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a rewriterule, which converts a subdomain into a folder.

For example, mystuff.localhost becomes localhost/mystuff

`otherthing.localhost/some/dir/here` becomes `localhost/otherthing/some/dir/here`

Comment: RewriteRule goes into htaccess? I never tried htaccess on localhost, so it goes in the same folder where the index file is?

Comment: Check the [apache documentation on mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html): rewriterules go in a file that's included in your conf.d.

Answer (score 28):

`http://*.lvh.me/` is an alias to `localhost`. Perfect for testing subdomains.

```
$ host lvh.me
lvh.me has address 127.0.0.1
$ host foo.lvh.me
foo.lvh.me has address 127.0.0.1
```

*Edit: 2016/07: lvho.st went away, swapped for working domain*

Comment: I was wondering where the domainname came from, but I assume it stands for "local vhost". Nice. For those, like me, wondering if it's some standard operating system thing: [no, simply a registered domain](http://network-tools.com/nslook/Default.asp?domain=lvho.st&type=1&server=ns2.nic.st&class=1&port=53&timeout=5000). It has [no support for IPv6](http://network-tools.com/nslook/Default.asp?domain=lvho.st&type=28&server=ns2.nic.st&class=1&port=53&timeout=5000) (yet) but I guess that doesn't matter for localhost.

Comment: Yup, some kind soul registered it for the masses :)

Comment: That's amazing! How did I never know about this?

Answer (score 9):

[lvh.me](http://lvh.me) is also an alias to localhost. Perfect for testing subdomains as [Jamo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/977939/jamo) say for [lvho.st](http://lvho.st).

Comment: this is now true only of lvh.me, and _not_ of lvho.st. lvh.me seems to support sub-sub-domains, and sub-sub-sub-domains, etc, which is handy (ex: http://foo.bar.bat.bongo.lvh.me)

Answer (score 2):

try adding another domain in serveralias:

```
ServerAlias something.localhost other.localhost
```

Comment: That's right for me, but I can just do it manually, or not? I would like to do it upon registration, and I don't really know that is a safe solution to put in other.localhost programatically, or just can I do it that way. - What I mean upon registration is that the user can change for himself a subdomain name, and reach that.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [dinamically configured mass virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html).

This allows you to define a single virtual host entry to handle all incoming requests for different hosts and delegate each request to the corresponding directory.

This way you avoid having to configure an new virtual host for each new domain you add. Instead you just create the directory in the file system and everything just works.

First you enable the mod_vhost_alias extension:

```
sudo a2enmod vhost_alias
```

Then configure your single virtual host entry like this:

```
# get the server name from the Host: header
UseCanonicalName Off

# this log format can be split per-virtual-host based on the first field
# this makes it easy to grep
LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" combined

<VirtualHost *:80>

    # the %0 is replaced by the host name on each request
    # if you want to use only part of the domain as directory
    # you would have to change the %0 for a %1 or %2 depending
    # on which part of the domain you want to take.
    VirtualDocumentRoot /your-main-directory/%0

    # configure your main directory anyway you want it
    <Directory /your-main-directory>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    #I have a single cgi-bin directory, but there is also a VirtualScriptAlias
    # available in case you need it.
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```