# How to make this kind of URL: mail.google.com

Tags: php, url

I don't know the name of this part of the domain name: **mail**.google.com

How do I implement something like that in my web application?

Please show me some tutorial for this. thank you

Comment: Just FYI, that is called a [subdomain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain).

Comment: This is a [subdomain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain).

Comment: thank you, now i won't have trouble searching for guides in google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not do this from within your web application. You need to setup an `A record` for your subdomain name. This is done using the control panel for your DNS server or editing the config files for BIND if you are running your own DNS server.

This [simple guide](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/dnsrecords.htm) explains the different types of DNS records.

Comment: hello, i'm running my lamp server in my own computer, is it possible to test that in my own local server?

Comment: Is there a domain name pointed to your local server? If you are using an external DNS server, see your provider's panel. If you are using `localhost`, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335680/subdomain-on-localhost

Comment: no, im accessing my test server via localhost/domain

Comment: thanks, managed to fix this. i followed this guide: http://thinkingnectar.com/2008/getting-ubuntu-to-work-creating-subdomain-in-localhost/

Comment: Glad you were able to solve your problem :)