# Route subdomain to a directory in server

Tags: apache

How is it possible to create a sub-domain in localhost. While using a windows machine I tried to edit the windows `host` file

```
  127.0.0.1               localhost
  127.0.0.1/subdomain     subdomain.localhost
```

to obtain something like this.

```
http://subdomain.localhost
```

**Update:**
First of all this question was asked without any context and this update is to improve the quality.
The following can be achieved by editing the vhosts file.

*vhosts:*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/subdomain/"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias subdomain.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And now on editing the hosts, the following can be solved.

*hosts*

```
127.0.0.0              subdomain.localhost
```

Now I found a better example, by using the `RewriteRule`
 (that works with any subdomain, not just localhost)

In the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/subdomains/sub/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

For a more general rule we could replace the last two lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/subdomains/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

I am not a mod_rewrite expert, kindly help with the improvements and guides. 
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been solved before. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335680/subdomain-on-localhost) might answer your question:

Comment: no problem... be sure to check the answer as accepted if it worked for you! - thanks!

Comment: The thing is i got files in localhost and i want to add a subdomain,

Comment: Stupid question, but have you tried adding a subdirectory for your subdomain?

Comment: Your link points to a similar example as what I answered with, it's just a different help site!